# Splitting a string by comma while ignoring other commas (not quoted)

Tags: php, regex

I am working with an API and getting results via an API. I am having trouble with the delimitation to split the array. Below is the sample example data I am receiving from the API:

> name: jo mamma, location: Atlanta, Georgia, description: He is a good
> boy, and he is pretty funny, skills: not much at all!

I would like to be able to split like so:

> name: jo mamma
>
> location: Atlanta, Georgia
>
> description: He is a good boy, and he is pretty funny
>
> skills: not much at all!

I have tried using the explode function and the regex preg_split.

```
$exploded = explode(",", $data);
$regex = preg_split("/,\s/", $data);
```

But not getting the intended results because its splitting also after boy, and after Georgia. Results below:

> name: jo mamma
>
> location: Atlanta
>
> Georgia
>
> description: He is a good boy
>
> and he is pretty funny
>
> skills: not much at all!

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your regex affects every comma. You need to change it and make one that searches for `, description`, `, skills` , and the like. Even then it's not 100% foolproof.

Comment: Try removing newlines from each string, it looks like the strings have been stored with newlines in them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this simple split using [Zero-Width Positive Lookahead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#zerowidth_positive_lookahead_assertion) . (It will split by only `,` after which there is text like `name:`).

```
$regex = preg_split("/,\s*(?=\w+\:)/", $data);
/*
Array
    (
       [0] => "name: jo mamma"
       [1] => "location: Atlanta, Georgia"
       [2] => "description: He is a good boy, and he is pretty funny"
       [3] => "skills: not much at all!"
    )
 */
```

> Learn more on lookahead and lookbehind from here : http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 2):

Use this regex:

```
name:\s(.*),\slocation:\s(.*),\sdescription:\s(.*),\sskills:\s(.*)

$text = 'name: jo mamma, location: Atlanta, Georgia, description: He is a good boy, and he is pretty funny, skills: not much at all!';
preg_match_all('/name:\s(.*),\slocation:\s(.*),\sdescription:\s(.*),\sskills:\s(.*)/', $text, $text_matches); 

for ($index = 1; $index < count($text_matches); $index++) {
    echo $text_matches[$index][0].'<br />';
}
```

**Output:**

```
jo mamma
Atlanta, Georgia
He is a good boy, and he is pretty funny
not much at all!
```

[**Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/uE3rY2/1)

Comment: If this is the best output we can get, I would suggest `preg_split('/,\s*\w+\:\s*/',  $text)` which will return the same output with less code.

Comment: @TareqMahmood Wouldn't you need parentheses in your regex to extract out specific groups?  If you want to update my answer that's fine, but please make sure the code still runs.

Comment: Not needed in my case, because, I am splitting the text into the output, there is no group to catch, I will get an array with the split texts.

Comment: Did you mean to edit your answer or putting an answer myself providing the same output?

Comment: Whichever you prefer.  This answer already has too many comments ^ ^

Comment: This worked. But I went with Tareq as it used less lines. Thanks though!

Comment: @user2052823 Make sure that his solution will cover all your edge cases.